# way to ignore intermediate column in an INSERT SELECT statement?

Tags: t-sql

For a `insert ... select` statement, is there a way to ignore a variable that is required for the select statement but should be inserted?

I'm using a `rank` function to select which data to `insert`. Unfortunately the `rank` function can't be called in the where clause.

```
insert into target_table(v1
                        ,v2
                        ,v3
                        )
select v1
      ,v2
      ,v3
      ,RANK() over (partition by group_col
                    order by order_col desc
                   ) as my_rank
from source_table
where my_rank > 1
```

The result is the following error:

> Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 The select list for the INSERT
>   statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of
>   SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

I know I can do this using a temporary table but would like to keep it in a single statement if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your main query inside a subquery.

```
INSERT INTO target_table
    (v1, v2, v3)
    SELECT q.v1, q.v2, q.v3
        FROM (SELECT v1, v2, v3, 
                     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY group_col ORDER BY order_col DESC) AS my_rank
                  FROM source_table) q
        WHERE q.my_rank > 1;
```

For SQL Server 2005+, you could also use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
WITH cteRank AS (
    SELECT v1, v2, v3, 
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY group_col ORDER BY order_col DESC) AS my_rank
        FROM source_table
)
INSERT INTO target_table
    (v1, v2, v3)
    SELECT v1, v2, v3
        FROM cteRank
        WHERE my_rank > 1;
```

Comment: Was hoping to avoid duplicating everything in a subquery but if noone else comes up with a better suggestion, I'll accept that.

Comment: @ChipMcCormick - You **need** to use a CTE or derived table for your `WHERE` clause to even work. You can't reference a column alias in the `WHERE` nor reference `RANK()` directly in a `WHERE` either.